# jquery - unable to invoke function for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a pagination ajax function displayed below:

```
$.fn.ajaxPagination = function() {

    return this.unbind('click').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //alert();return;

        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('disabled')) {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var wrapper = $(this).closest('.content-wrapper');

            wrapper.addClass('loader-bg');


            $.post(href + '&ajax=1', function(response) {

                wrapper.removeClass('loader-bg');
                wrapper.html(response);
                sig.init();

                return false;
            });

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

I invoke it using the code:

```
$('.pagination > li > a').ajaxPagination();
```

Sometimes the anchor links are displayed from the result of ajax. So they become dynamically created elements. I am not able to invoke this function due to the dynamic creation of these anchor tags. I know how to solve this case if it was a click or any other event. But this is the invokation of a function. How to solve this issue? Any ideas are welcome. :)

Comment: Add the click event to the dynamically created anchors after they are created.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use event delegation. see https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ 
You should bind click on a parent element containing all you dynamically created anchors, matching a selector, and you do not have to bother about adding the click event to the dynamically created elements.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed the issue using this code snippet:

$(document).on('click', '.pagination > li > a', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxPagination();
}
);

Comment: That's delegation to document. It works, BUT delegated events handling it is efficient when you try to bind them to the closest parent that is not dynamic. Why? Consider a click event that bubbles up to this delegated event handler (document in your case), jQuery has to go through the list of delegated event handlers and see if the originating element matches any of the selectors in the delegated event handlers. And a lot of clicks will bubble up to document.